# Can't get Jquery datepicker to work in my asp.net mvc project

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have a simple page where i want to add a datepicker to my textboxfor and just modify the format but there is simply nothing showing on the page, I have tried to import all the scripts they said necessary on jquery datepicker documentation here : https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Here is my cshtml page on my project with what I have tried to make it work as of now:

```
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls
@using InscriptionCentreFormation.Controllers
@using InscriptionCentreFormation.Models
@model INSC_Inscription
@{
 ViewBag.Title = "InscriptionFormation";
 Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<br />
@using (Html.BeginForm("InscriptionFormation", "DetailProduit"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.idOccurenceFormation);
    <div style="width:550px;">
        <br />
        <span style="float:left"><b>Date de naissance :</b></span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateNaissanceChaine, new { Style = "float:right;width:350px;",id="datepicker" })
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateNaissanceChaine, "", new { @class = "text-danger"})      

        </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="S'inscrire" style="width:200px; text-align:center;"/>
}
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
    });
});
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

So i don't know what im doing wrong according to the documentation it seems to be pretty simple to implement so maybe im just missing something important because the field only shows as a normal textbox

Any tip would be really helpful

**Update**

here is the error from the console :

```
TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
```

**Finally  I found the problem it seems that jquery-ui was already loaded on the layout page and created problems since it was loaded twice**

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

Comment: Because you are loading `jquery` and `jquery-ui` after initialization of datepicker.

Comment: You do not have an textbox with `id="datepicker"`. Change the script to `$("#DateNaissanceChaine").datepicker({ ...` (you have added that `id` to the validation message placeholder)

Comment: Actually he has an element with `id="datepicker"` but it is not `textbox`. It is validation message.

Comment: You dateformat is not valid. Use 'dd-mm-yy'

Comment: Do not change the code in your question and invalidate the comments and answers that have been added.

Comment: @StephenMuecke okay should i have posted an edited format then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you're trying to use the `datepicker` library *before* you've included it in the page. Put the `<script>` block containing your code *after* the references to jQuery.js and jQueryUI.js.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
      format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
    });
  });
</script>
```

Also note that you put the `datepicker` id on the validation label, not on the input element as it should be:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateNaissanceChaine, new { Style = "float: right; width: 350px;", id = "datepicker })
<br />
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateNaissanceChaine, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

I'd also strongly suggest you put the styling rules in classes, then add those classes in the HTML. putting inline styles in the HTML just makes the code muddy, and isn't a good separation of concerns

Comment: I put it before and still nothing shows on the page

Comment: That's because you set the `datepicker` id on the `ValidationMessageFor`, when it should be in the `TextBoxFor` instead. I updated my answer for you

Comment: In that case please check the console and report any errors you find

Comment: The error you edited in to the question implies you haven't included jqueryUI properly, or are still trying to execute `datepicker()` in the wrong place. In isolation your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/8rs7sf5p/

Comment: I guess the problem is in my project then so thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 0):

Move this script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        format: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });
});
```

below Jquery Import

Also move the `id="datepicker"` to TextBoxFor().